# Feature Attributes window shifts when creating/labelling features QGIS 3.20.1

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, dockable-window

I am running QGIS 3.20.1, and every time I add a feature to my shapefile, the Feature Attributes window shifts downwards - to the point I have to click and drag it upwards to fill in the attribute I need to, about every half-dozen features I create.

The window will open near the top of the screen, and end up outside my field of view on the bottom.

I've had no luck seeing an answer on how to dock this window, and never encountered this issue with other versions of QGIS. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello! I'm using Windows

Comment: If it didn't occur on previous versions (I can confirm there is no such issue in 3.18.3) perhaps file a bug report on the official QGIS github page.

Comment: Thank you @she_weeds - I am going to reinstall an earlier version and report the issue.

Comment: I am also experience this issue with version 3.26.3 on Windows

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been resolved with version 3.32.1 of QGIS. Have a great day!